User terraform is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem
community!
I need your advice and help with my terraform situation.
I've set up my env:
Terraform v1.9.8 on linux_amd64 and Ubuntu 22.04 in WSL2.0 for Win10.
Now i am deploying environment in AWS and i have pre-requirements to hold tfstate file in s3bucket and to lock it via dynamodb.
When i run terraform apply i see the following error message:
# terraform apply
Acquiring state lock. This may take a few moments...
╷
│ Error: Error acquiring the state lock
│
│ Error message: operation error DynamoDB: PutItem, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: 675BRV1T9IUNPI, api error AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:iam::***:user/terraform is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem on resource:
│ arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:***:table/terraform-asav-lock-table because no identity-based policy allows the dynamodb:PutItem action
│ Unable to retrieve item from DynamoDB table "terraform-asav-lock-table": operation error DynamoDB: GetItem, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: 0N2J50TQTG2AKQIM, api error AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:iam::***:user/terraform is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:GetItem on
│ resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:***:table/terraform-asav-lock-table because no identity-based policy allows the dynamodb:GetItem action
│
│ Terraform acquires a state lock to protect the state from being written
│ by multiple users at the same time. Please resolve the issue above and try
│ again. For most commands, you can disable locking with the "-lock=false"
│ flag, but this is not recommended.

And my provider.tf is:
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "5.50.0"
      
    }
  }

  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "asavbacket"
    encrypt        = true
    key            = "terraform.tfstate/state"
    region         = "us-east-1"
    access_key     = "***"
    secret_key     = "***"
    dynamodb_table = "terraform-asav-lock-table"
  }
}

Please help my to understand, why this error is appears?
I've tried to add IAM policy to IAM user terraform to make for appropriate access to s3 bucket and dynamodb table
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "EnableIAMUserPermissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "kms:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:***:key/d6c67"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "StateBucketObjectAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
                "dynamodb:GetItem"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:***:table/terraform-asav-lock-table"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::asavbacket"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::asavbacket/terraform.tfstate/state"
        }
    ]
}

Update. I've found solution for this error. I created Administrator group in my AWS account and attached user terraform to this group.
But now i've got next error:
Error message: operation error DynamoDB: PutItem, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: H3QGJJHIOBPHFUAPNDE26HS82JVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG, api error ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key terraform.tfstate in the item
│ Unable to retrieve item from DynamoDB table "terraform-asav-lock-table": operation error DynamoDB: GetItem, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: 2Q9SQ7M20CT913K5RU3NHUPUIRVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG, api error ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema

Could help me to fix it?

try key = "terraform.tfstate". Also check your.tfignore file.

This issue is stating the you provided the wrong key for your GetItem request. It seems you only have a partition key specified, so when you do your GetItem ensure you pass the correct partition key name and value type.
table.get_item(Key={"terraform.tfstate": "some value"})


Problem with access to dynamodb table, not with s3bucket

I'm not taking about S3.

Understood. But I found another solution. I created a user group called 'Administrator' and added my user to this group. I don’t know if it’s the right way, but it worked
